# How to check the disk size of a Vagrant Box?

Tags: vagrant

Is there any way for me to check the disk size of a Vagrant Box, preferably before downloading/using it?

Ideally, I'd want to go to [the Vagrant Box search page](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search) and be able to see what the disk size is before using it in my Vagrantfile.

Otherwise, I'd at least like to look at the disk size *after* downloading the box. E.g.

```
$ vagrant box list -i
hashicorp/bionic64 (virtualbox, 1.0.282)  <--- show disk size here 
minimal/xenial64   (virtualbox, 16.04.2)
```

Right now its all trial and error. I have to actually create a VM and run `df` in it to see how big the disk is.

```
vagrant@minimal-xenial:~$ df -h .
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/minimal--xenial--vg-root   57G  731M   53G   2% /
vagrant@minimal-xenial:~$
```

(And why does a "minimal" box create a 60G disk? I am sure xenial64 can comfortably fit in 20G)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check how much space each box takes up when vagrant has downloaded it to its internal storage. Vagrant store the boxes in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes` in a subdir for each box.

- Mac OS X and Linux: `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`
- Windows: `C:/Users/USERNAME/.vagrant.d/boxes`

This however, does not say how much additional space they will use when firing up an instance of a box. And it does not say the size before a box is downloaded.

It is up to the one who created the box to set the sizes required etc.

See here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base

See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155708/where-does-vagrant-download-its-box-files-to

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**Virtualbox-specific answer**

As the [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1706210/534423) said, Vagrant downloads boxes into `<unix-or-windows-path>/.vagrant.d/boxes`.

If one of your Vagrant providers is Virtualbox and the box you're interested in supports Virtualbox, you can use the `VBoxManage showmediuminfo` command to get more detailed info about the Virtualbox disk medium. For example:

```
$ VBoxManage showmediuminfo ~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-focal64/20240306.0.0/virtualbox/ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg.vmdk 
UUID:           081ca5d3-d839-4a43-94fc-2e146c76b3dc
Parent UUID:    base
State:          inaccessible
Access Error:   UUID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} of the medium '/home/villapx/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-focal64/20240306.0.0/virtualbox/ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg.vmdk' does not match the value {081ca5d3-d839-4a43-94fc-2e146c76b3dc} stored in the media registry ('/home/villapx/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml')
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/villapx/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-focal64/20240306.0.0/virtualbox/ubuntu-focal-20.04-cloudimg.vmdk
Storage format: VMDK
Format variant: dynamic streamOptimized
Capacity:       40960 MBytes
Size on disk:   581 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
```

You can see here that the disk is 40960 Megabytes in size.

(Note, I can't say I understand the UUID warning that this command is printing)